# How to change css styles on alloy-ui form validator?

Tags: css, liferay, alloy-ui

How i can change css styles of input fields and labels when alloy ui form validator detect a empty field?

This is one of the fields

```
<label for='<portlet:namespace  />formnumdoc'>
    <liferay-ui:message key="formulario.DOCUMENT"/><span class="red_mini">*</span>
</label>
<input type='text' id='<portlet:namespace  />formnumdoc' name='formnumdoc' />
```

And this is Alloy Ui script

```
YUI().use('aui-form-validator', function(Y) {
    new Y.FormValidator({
        boundingBox : '#frmEntity',
        rules : {
            formnumdoc : {
                required : true
            }
        },
        fieldStrings: {
            formnumdoc: {
                required: '<liferay-ui:message key="formulario.REQUIRED_FIELD_ALERT"/>'
              }
            }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the CSS that [AlloyUI `FormValidator`](http://alloyui.com/api/classes/A.FormValidator.html) applies with the [`errorClass`](http://alloyui.com/api/classes/A.FormValidator.html#attr_errorClass) and [`validClass`](http://alloyui.com/api/classes/A.FormValidator.html#attr_validClass) attributes:

```
new Y.FormValidator({
    /* your code here... */
    errorClass: 'your-new-error-class',
    validClass: 'your-new-valid-class'
});
```

You may also want to check out [`containerErrorClass`](http://alloyui.com/api/classes/A.FormValidator.html#attr_containerErrorClass) and [`containerValidClass`](http://alloyui.com/api/classes/A.FormValidator.html#attr_containerValidClass).